# How can we not lose our work with git if we are coding simultaneously

Tags: git, repository, git-commit, git-push, git-pull

I am new with git and I'm basically only using `pull`, `commit` and `push`; right now a question in my head popped up.

Lets say we are 2 people coding right now on the same project; don't we both risk of losing our work if one of us does `pull` then `commit` and `push`?

If i `push` first, then he will have to `pull` and his work is wiped out to receive mine; if he pushes first my work is wiped out when i `pull`; if we just `commit` but not `push` we end up having 2 different versions of the project in our local repositories; so what should I do?

My only idea for now is that we should message eachother to not code simultaneously, can git manage this situation somehow?

Comment: Use different branches, then merge your branches with master when your work is done and fix the merge conflicts.

Comment: Your question is predicated on the idea that `pull` and `push` are copy operations. Which they're not. Avoiding the problem you describe **is precisely the essence** of source control in general, and git in particular.

Comment: When several people are working on the same files, git can refuse to `pull` or `push` because of conflicts. You have to fix them manually before you can proceed.

Comment: @MickaelB. I'd suggest the same, but for the record, even a unique branch and 10 people working on it is fine in some contexts. Conflicts to be solved, most likely, but no "overwrite" ever.

Comment: @RomainValeri yes that's correct. So if i were to pull with having some different lines from the main repository my workspace doesn't just get deleted and replaced with the main repository but it will keep both?

Comment: @wattbatt a tip: create a new repo with test files in it, and try out things that you think will cause conflicts.